# Python - Filter BS4 content

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Current code:

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'hidden'

res = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
bs4_content = soup.find_all(class_='user-post-count')
print(bs4_content)
```

Only content I manage to get is

```
[<p class="user-post-count">This user has made <strong>5 posts</strong>
</p>]
```

I'm trying to only get the content between the strong tags.

Thank you, all help much appreciated

Comment: You will not get this content with requests. You need to use `selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner `.find_all`

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'hidden'

res = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
bs4_content = soup.find_all(class_='user-post-count')
for strong in bs4_content.find_all('strong'):
    print(strong.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction.

I had to remove soup.find_all and replace with soup.find from line 9 for it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS Selector `.user-post-count strong`, which selects the  `<strong>` tags under the  `user-post-count` class.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<p class="user-post-count">This user has made <strong>5 posts</strong>
</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select('.user-post-count strong'):
    print(tag.text)
```

Output:

```
5 posts
```